# Create Connection beetween TextFilter and List

Tags: 2013, filter, connection

I have created a text filter webpart on my page and a list webpart app on the same page. If I edit the filter webpart it says that the filter is not connected and I should open the webpart editing tool to create the connection. This seems good as I'd love to create a connection but I cant seem to find the option where I can connect the filter to the list. In the standard editing window right of the webpart there are the following options:

```
Filter
    Filtername
    Extended Filter Options
        Maximum text length
        Default value
        Width in pixel
View
    Width
    Height
    Title
    Chrome state
    Chrome type
Layout
    Direction
    Zone
    Zone index
Advanced
    Allow minimize
    allow close
    allow hide
    allow zone change
    allow connections (set to true)
    export mode
    title-url
    description
    help-url
    help-mode
    catalogsymbol
    titlesymbol
    import error message
    target audience
```

I cant seem to find a link to create a connection, am I doing something wrong? Thanks in advance and have a nice day